# Validate Email in php

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What’s wrong with this RegEx for validating emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076573/whats-wrong-with-this-regex-for-validating-emails)
>   [How to verify if a email address exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750175/how-to-verify-if-a-email-address-exists)
>   [How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email)

I was wondering if it was possible to validate an email address with php (w/library or without). When I say validate I don't mean a regex match I mean verify that the email address is actually a valid address in which emails can be sent.

Comment: Actually, according to [google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Validate+Email+site:stackoverflow.com) this question has been discussed 18,300 times on this site.

Comment: Before you downvote the question as duplicate trouble yourself with reading more than the title. If you read the question you will see he is not asking about regex.

Comment: If you are doing a verification on your form using ajax to check email addresses in addition to regex validation. A simple thing you can do is verify the domain of the email address is valid. In this context, I think that's a good enough test for an email address.

Comment: @Majid this is an **exact duplicate**, be it php or otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750175/how-to-verify-if-a-email-address-exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is verification rather than validation, and yes it is possible and [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Email-Address-Verification-with-PHP/2/) is a tutorial which shows how you go about it.

Comment: Thank you, it's not full proof but it will be suitable for what I'm doing

Comment: The regex in that article is *awful*.  Please use a [RFC compliant validator](http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail/) instead.

Comment: I won't be using the regex, but I like the idea of using DNS to at least verify the hostname.

Answer (score 2):

No, the only way you can truly validate an email is to send it an email containing a validation link.

Comment: Of course, that can be done with PHP.

Comment: So what if I used the mail() function and it returned false?

Comment: All that means is the PHP function failed. That says very little about whether the email address actually exists.

Comment: @Albino That still doesn't tell you anything

Comment: It is blatantly false that you can not validate an email.  There are [some RFC validation libraries](http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail/) available that will validate any internet-routable email address as *well-formed*.  They won't validate local addresses or local domains properly.  However, it is very true that sending an email to the address in question is *the best* way to ensure it's legit.