# Problem validating e-mail with RegEx using preg_match() in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I can't get working a `preg_match()` in PHP to validate an e-mail address. I've tested the RegEx expression that I've found on Internet with the http://www.regexer.com tool and works fine with the same input I'm using on my PHP application.

RegEx expression:

```
^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$
```

Regexer: http://regexr.com?2sr2a

And I'm applying it like this in PHP:

```
$email   = "local@test.com";
$pattern = "/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix";

if (false == preg_match($pattern, $email))
    echo "false";
```

And of course, I get a false with this e-mail and others that I've tested. The expression I think is well formed because on regexer I can test and it works. What I'm applying incorrectly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The regex is ok.

Comment: The example code works fine for me.

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/IkQo2

Comment: @SirDarius: Thank you. That was the problem! :)

Comment: [Gazillion duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=validate+email+php) - use PHP's native `filter_var` instead of a regex

Comment: @Kobi/@bisko: Probably depends on PHP version/configuration? Escaping the \ works on my environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate Email in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499192/validate-email-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash characters need to be properly escaped by doubling them like this:

```
$pattern = "/^([a-z0-9\\+_\\-]+)(\\.[a-z0-9\\+_\\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\\-]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix";
```

Using this pattern, preg_match correctly returns 1.

Comment: They don't normally. Backslashes are only stripped when they preceed another backslash, double quote, $, octal literals, or one of the ascii escapes \r \n \t. `print "\."` will print `\.`

Comment: Although it's not mandatory to escape backslashes, it is highly recommended to do so in double-quoted strings, especially if you might accidentally insert a character causing the creation of a valid escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is wrong in your code but here you have a fully functional php function for checking an email address:

```
function is_validemail($email) 
{
     return preg_match('/^[\w.-]+@([\w.-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/is', $email);
}

$email = "local@root.ws";

if(is_validemail($email)) { echo ("email validated"); } else { echo ("invalid email given"); }
```

Hope it helps!