# PHP Validate email if value is not empty

Tags: php, forms, email, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate Email in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499192/validate-email-in-php)

how to validate email IF user did fill up form field  ( do not validate if field is not modified  ) ?

Example:

```
if ($formemail ="" ) /* user DIDN'T enter email/not filled up email field  */   
{
/* do not validate and do not =mail($,$,$,$) */
}
```

but if field is modified THEN validate 
if its ok then =mail($,$,$,$)

Comment: $formemail =""  should be $formemail ==""

Comment: where you assigning the $dormemail ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 attributes to get that done.

```
<input type="text" class="email" email="email" required />
```

The required attribute makes sure the field has some value,and the email attribute checks if the value is an email. :)

Comment: Yes, but this html5 input type is not 100% supported across all browsers

Comment: Server-side validation should always take place. Doing it in the browser should strictly be seen as a UI improvement in response to the user.

Comment: True,server-side validation should always take place. sorry about that! I usually check if the field is empty,however I leave it to HTML5 to check if an email was entered.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
if($formemail != ""){
    //validate and send
}
```

You don't need an else statement here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (from http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585):

```
function checkEmail($email) {
  if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $email)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

if (!empty($formemail) && checkEmail($formemail)) {
  //Mail it!
}
```

Comment: - **Don't try this at home kids.** Learn about [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).