# php, check if mail is valid

Tags: php, email

I know that there is a ton of solutions to this problem but i need to validate email in a contact form.

this is my php mailer so far:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])){ 
     $to = "mail@mail.something"; 
     $subject = "new message"; 
     $firstname = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $message = $_POST['message']; 
     $headers = "From: $email"; 
     $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ; 
     if($sent) 
     {echo "<script>alert('thanks for the message:) ');</script>"; 
    }else
        {echo "<script>alert('sorry, message wasn't send');</script>"; }
    }
?>
```

I have tried with filter_var

```
$result = filter_var( 'something@something.something', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
```

but, doesn't work.

If my way to sent mail through contact form isn't the "best practice way" feel free to correct me and send me on the right path :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate Email in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499192/validate-email-in-php)

Comment: Why does `filter_var` not work?

Comment: put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check if there;s any error

Comment: I'll try :) 
Luke, i know but i have tried some different approaches and it still doesn't work, thats why i am asking. 

Mischa, yea :D i would like to know aswell...

Comment: I think you may need to describe what is not working about it.

Comment: "but, doesn't work." tells us nothing.  Enable error reporting and tell us the error code

Comment: Well.. i would like to tell you more about it, but all i get is a blank screen when i ask if $result and validate is true, then send mail. 
I will try error reporting as soon as i get home from work.

Comment: You can check your php log file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate an Email in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you show us your HTML we can help further, but with just your PHP we don't have much to work with.

Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your php page to print your errors.

I am not sure what is causing your errors.  But i would like you to try the following code.  Replace your if statement with this.

Future note, to add a javascript alert in php you should format it this way,

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo '<script language="javascript">'; //echo open tag
    echo 'alert("Your message has been sent")'; // echo alert
    echo '</script>'; //echo close tag
}else{
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Your message was not successful")';
    echo '</script>'; 
}
```

Comment: Your welcome, try replacing your whole if statement and mail send to the bottom php code on this answer.  If you have any errors please post back.

Comment: If this doesnt work for your needs, check out the top answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php