# Email Verification PHP

Tags: php, email

I have the following code which (I think) will only verify the domain of the email address.

```
$EmailAddress = "user@domain.com";

list($User, $Domain) = explode("@", $EmailAddress);
$DomainExists = checkdnsrr($Domain, 'MX');
if($DomainExists==true){
    // Email domain exists
}
else{
    // Email domain does not exist
}
```

If I can, how do I verify the `$User` part?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to verify if a email address exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750175/how-to-verify-if-a-email-address-exists)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if an email address exist through PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239533/how-to-know-if-an-email-address-exist-through-php)

Comment: @Willian — the answer is still the same, the problem is language independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only guaranteed way to make sure `user@example.com` exists is sending them an e-mail with a verification link.

Here's another post on how to do that: [Easiest way for PHP email verification link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794959/easiest-way-for-php-email-verification-link)

Answer (score 5):

The only way you can tell if an email address exists is to send email to it with a task for the user to perform (usually clicking on a link), for the email not to be caught in spam filters, and for the recipient to perform the task.